# существует ли плагин dart для google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, dart

Есть файл **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ABC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="text"></h1>
    <script src="main.dart" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Есть файл **main.dart**

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
 querySelector('#text').text = 'Hello World!';
}
```

Существует ли такой плагин ***dart*** для браузера ***google chrome***, что бы просто открыв файл **index.html** в браузере, там отработал код ***Dart***, как ***JavaScript***? Или такого не существует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первой версии `dart`, был специальный браузер для него "[Dartium](https://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/tech-preview-of-chromium-with-dart.html)". На данный момент, проект был закрыт. Теперь `dart` компилируется в `js` через [dart2js](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2js).
И плагина скорее всего не существует...

[Подробнее о Dart Web](https://dart.dev/web).

Comment: Уважаемый MiT! Огромное Вам спасибо!